# Ruby: nil can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)

Tags: ruby

The error is on line 12 and I'm not sure why I can't add the numbers. Any help is much appreciated.
Instructions: Write a method that takes an array of numbers. If a pair of numbers in the array sums to zero, return the positions of those two numbers. If no pair of numbers sums to zero, return `nil`.

```
def two_sum(nums)
  idx1 = 0
  idx2 = 1
  while idx1 < nums.length

    if nums[idx1] + nums[idx2] == 0

      return [idx1, idx2]

    end
    idx2 += 1
    if idx2 == nums.length
      idx1 += 1
      idx2 = idx1 + 1
    end
  end
  return nil 
end

puts("two_sum([1, 3, 5, -3]) == [1, 3]: #{two_sum([1, 3, 5, -3]) == [1, 3]}")
puts("two_sum([1, 3, 5]) == nil: #{two_sum([1, 3, 5]) == nil}")
```

Comment: For those who will find this 'question' by the title if you want to convert `nil` into a Fixnum append `.to_i` on it: `nil.to_i`.  Put it on whatever variable you're using `myvar.to_i`.  This will convert `nil` to `0`.

Comment: I tried searching the problem but didn't find my specific problem or was too ignorant to recognize an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`idx2` could overflow capacity of your array:

Imagine. `nums = [1,2,3]`, so `nums.length` is 3, `idx1 = 1`, `idx2 = 2`

```
idx2 += 1 # ok now idx2 is 3
if idx2 == nums.length # ok true, idx2 == 3
  idx1 += 1 # mmm, cool idx1 now 2
  idx2 = idx1 + 1 # idx2 is 3
end
```

So in next iteration you will call

```
nums[idx2]
# same as
nums[3]
# ERROR! there is only 3 numbers in nums
```

And try to understand this code

```
def two_sums(nums)
  nums[0..-2].each.with_index do |n,i|
    nums[i+1..-1].each.with_index do |m,j|
      return [i, i+j+1] if m + n == 0
    end
  end
  nil
end
```